# to debug Wicket framework 1.3.5 on Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, wicket

I have a search page where it has several input components like text-box, drop-down, radio buttons, etc. For a particular brand value selected in a drop-down and hit searching, I am getting a blank table. though it is visible on IE browser. it is a simple DB retrieval call. the page is build on Apache-wicket framework version 1.3.5
I am using a chrome browser version 57 - 64 bit, while debugging the code the count / size of the result-set remains same for both browsers.

please suggest me how to debug the issue, as I don't have any idea on wicket framework, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First check whether the generated HTML response is different between Chrome and IE. If it is the same then open Chrome's Dev Tools > Elements tab and look for CSS rules which would hide the table's content.